# Read from a text file

Tags: c#, file-io, windows-store-apps, windows-8.1

I created a project and I want to read an array of strings from a .txt which is static. What is the right way to do that?
I created myfile.txt and put it in Asset folder of my project. Is it better to create a new folder? And then how can I read that file?

Comment: This is probably the most google-able question in a while.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to do so is by using

```
file3 = await localFolder.GetFileAsync(path);
IList<String> readFile = await Windows.Storage.FileIO.ReadLinesAsync(file3);
```

where path represents the file path or file name (depending on the location of the file)
It does not save it in an array as you wish but you can have the same functionality of arrays by utilizing lists. If you do not know how to utilize lists then there is more reason to use this method as practice and help you learn lists

Answer (score 0):

You can read the file in various ways. Look at `StreamReader` for reading
See the [docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/db5x7c0d%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
    using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("c:\\TestFile.txt"))
    {
        while (sr.Peek() >= 0) 
        {
            Console.WriteLine(sr.ReadLine());
        }
    }
```

Note the need to escape a backslashes `\` in path names if you don't use raw strings.

Comment: I'm not sure, but http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh454050%28v=vs.110%29.aspxmentions StreamReader.